# How can this bipartite matching solution be improved?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, matching, bipartite

I'm working through codefights and am attempting the busyHolidays challenge from the Instacart company challenges.

The challenge provides three arrays. Shoppers contains strings representing the start and end times of their shifts. Orders contains strings representing the start and end times of the orders, and leadTime contains integers representing the number of minutes it takes to complete the job.

The goal is to determine if the orders can be matched to shoppers such that each shopper has only one order and each order has a shopper. An order may only be matched to a shopper if the shopper can both begin and complete it within the order time.

I have a solution that passes 19/20 tests, but since I can't see the last test I have no idea what's going wrong. I originally spent a couple days trying to learn algorithms like Edmond's Algorithm and the Hungarian Algorithm, but my lack of CS background and weakness in math kind of bit me in the ass and I can't seem to wrap my head around how to actually implement those methodologies, so I came up with a solution that involves weighting each node on each side of the graph according to its number of possible connections. I would appreciate it if anyone could help me take a look at my solution and either point out where it might be messing up or suggest a more standard solution to the problem in a way that might be easier for someone without formal training in algorithms to understand. Thanks in advance.

I'll put the code in a gist since it's fairly length

Code: https://gist.github.com/JakeTompkins/7e1afc4722fb828f26f8f6a964774a25

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't see any reason to think that the algorithm you're writing is actually going to work so the question about how you might be messing it up doesn't seem to be relevant.

You have correctly identified this as an instance of the assignment problem.  More specifically this is the "maximum bipartite matching" problem, and the Edmonds-Karp algorithm is the simpliest way to solve it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)

However, this is an algorithm for finding the maximum flow in a network, which is a larger problem than simple bipartite matching, and the explanations of this algorithm are really a lot more complicated than you need.  It's understandable that you had some trouble implementing this from the literature, but actually when the problem is reduced to simple (unweighted) bipartite matching, the algorithm is easy to understand:

1. Make an initial assignment
2. Try to find an improvement
3. Repeat until no more improvements can be found.

For bipartite matching, an "improvement" always has the same form, which is what makes this problem easy to solve.  To find an improvement, you have to find a path that connects an unassigned shopper to an unassigned order, following these rules:

- The path can go from any shopper to any order he/she could fulfill but does not
- The path can go from any order only to the shopper that is fulfilling it in the current assignment.

You use bread-first search to find the shortest path, which will correspond to the improvement that changes the smallest number of existing assignments.

The path you find will necessarily have an odd number of edges, and the even-numbered edges will be assignments.  To implement the improvement, you remove those assignments and replace them with the odd-numbered edges.  There's one more of those, which is what makes it an improvement.  It looks like this:

```
PREVIOUS       PATH FOUND      IMPROVED ASSIGNMENT

    1              1                  1
                 /                  /
A              A                  A
  \              \     
    2              2                  2
                 /                  /
B              B                  B           
  \              \       
    3              3                  3
                 /                  /
C              C                  C
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. The logic behind what I was trying was that if a job can only be done by one employee then it that connection should be prioritized, and that subsequent connections should prioritize the least in-demand shopper so as to affect the ability of the fewest number of other jobs to be filled. Again, I have no formal background in this stuff so I took my best stab at it. Thank you for your explanation, it cleared things up a bit and I think I should be able to implement it now. Much appreciated.

Comment: You can reduce the time taken on average by using rules like that to pick your initial assignment, but they'll be fooled by some instances so you'll still need the iterative improvement.  To find a situation where the rules fail, try thinking of ways to trick the rules into creating a subset of N unassigned shoppers that can only connect to N-1 unassigned orders, or a set of N unassigned orders that can only connect to N-1 unassigned shoppers.